# Ecommerce Tracking with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've added the Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking JS to my website and now I need to see if it's working.  My problem is, I have no idea what section of the admin I need to look in.

Does anyone know where in the Analytics admin, the Ecommerce Tracking is?

Answer (score 1):

On your Google Analytics dashboard, the left navigation should contain the following items:

- Dashboard
- Intelligence Beta
- Visitors
- Traffic Sources
- Content
- Goals
- **Ecommerce**

If you **don't** see Ecommerce listed, your profile is not set up as an ecommerce site in Google Analytics.

To rectify this:

1. Go to Analytis Settings, find your profile and choose `Edit`.
2. In the Main Website Profile Information seciotn, choose `Edit`.
3. Under E-Commerce Website, choose the radio option `Yes, an E-Commerce Site`
4. `Save Changes`

Answer (score 0):

its also worth double checking that everything is sending correctly.
Check with this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna